# Verb 'translate'?

Tags: expressions

When you don't want to use the verb "translate" because you feel it is exaggerated in your context. I just wonder if "make it in English" works. What would you say alternatively?

> I'm not sure if these English words, both of which I roughly made in English, are correct.

Comment: What is the context.  Translate means to convert from one language to another.  It isn't an exaggerated word. If you mean take text in one language and re-make it in English, the you need to use "translate"  So.... Please *give the context as an example sentence*  You can edit the example sentence into your question.

Comment: For example, "I'm not sure if these English words, both of which I roughly translated, are correct."

Comment: So you are asking if you can say something like  "I'm not sure if these English words, both of which I roughly made in English, are correct."   That is a good example and I'll add it too the question.  In future remember you can edit your question instead of adding extra information in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Translate is always going to be correct: it means

> to turn into one's own or another language ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/translate))

It isn't exaggerated, but possible alternatives if talking to somebody else might be

> What does that mean in English?
> How do you say that in English?
> What's that in English?

In other situations, although I suspect this might be regional and context dependent (so I wouldn't advise using it, but for the sake of completeness) I sometimes use "put" or even "go". I would never write this though (except here to explain how I'd say it!).

> These leaflets need to be put into German, French and Spanish before the deadline.
> Sandrine, could you put this paragraph into French for me please?

> These leaflets need to go into German, French and Spanish before the deadline.

Comment: Yes, I thought it might be quite formal, but I guess there's no good alternatives.

Comment: It might *seem* formal, but it isn't really very formal. It is just the normal word.

Comment: @JamesK, it does sound completely normal, I just wasn't sure if I'd necessarily say it in a 'chat'! I'll alter my answer so I don't put people off using it.

Answer (score 0):

Say it in English. "Make it..." doesn't work.
Alternatively, "express" it.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for the helpful information. I don't need to use "Make it".